# Error: 'reverse' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, std, reverse

I created a program to reverse a sentence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    string reversedSentence;
    int i2 = 0;

    cout << "Type in a sentence..." << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);

    reversedSentence = sentence;
    reverse(reversedSentence.begin(), reversedSentence.end());

    cout << sentence << endl;
}
```

But when I try to compile it with MinGW G++, this happens:

```
SentenceReverser.cpp: In function 'int main()':
SentenceReverser.cpp:16:5: error: 'reverse' was not declared in this scope
   16 |     reverse(reversedSentence.begin(), reversedSentence.end());
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

I don't know what I've done wrong. Help?

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what is wrong, you have no method named reverse...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`std::reverse()` is defined in the `algorithm` header.  Include that:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Also, [avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).